# Create Pop up window from a ListView in sharepoint 2013

Tags: jquery, sharepoint-2010, popup, sharepoint-2013

I have a list view as shown below in the Image and this is a task list.

On click of of Apply button , I would like to display the Position descrption Column value in a pop up window (may be in modal dialog box) and these description should be corresponding to  the rows.

Can somebody provide an idea how to achieve this?